# C++ decision tree with pruning

Tags: c++, machine-learning, decision-tree

Can you recommend me a good decision tree C++ class with support for continous features and pruning(its very important)? Im writing a simple classifier(two classes) using 9 features. I've been using Waffles recently, but looks like tree is overfitting so i get Precision around 82% but Recall is around 51% which is inacceptable. Waffles have no ability to prune decision trees, and im running out of time :)

Comment: No chance to create one on your own...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have to answer my own question, as long as no one answered.
I used decision tree implementation from OpenCV library, very flexible implementation and fast enough for my tasks.